# Time all IPython commands by default

Tags: ipython

I would love for there to be an implicit `%time` run for every command I use in IPython. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It does not specifically answer your question regarding ipython but there is an extension for jupyter notebooks which might help you: ExecuteTime. It adds the runtime information to each cell.

https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/execute_time/readme.html

Comment: Thanks! That is a useful answer for many others I am sure, but I do not use notebooks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find information on this but can only find another "unanswered" question:

- [Is there a way to add timing by default to ipython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646507/is-there-a-way-to-add-timing-by-default-to-ipython)

It does appear to be possible by using the IPython extension API (or 'hooks' in older versions)

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/callbacks.html#ipython-events

```py
>>> %load_ext ipython-timer
>>> print("Hello, world!")
Hello, world!
Elapsed time: 0.00043 seconds
```

- `ipython-timer.py`

```py
import time

class CellTimer:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.shell = ip
        self.initialized = False
        self.exiting = False

    def pre_execute(self):
        self.time = time.perf_counter()

    # Don't print when exiting, is this the proper way to detect this?
    def pre_run_cell(self, info):
        if info.raw_cell in {'exit', 'exit()'}:
            self.exiting = True

    def post_execute(self):
        if self.initialized and not self.exiting:
            now = time.perf_counter()
            print(f"Elapsed time: {now - self.time:.5f} seconds")
        else:
            self.initialized = True

events = []

def load_ipython_extension(ip):
    timer = CellTimer(ip)
    ip.events.register('pre_execute',  timer.pre_execute)
    ip.events.register('pre_run_cell', timer.pre_run_cell)
    ip.events.register('post_execute', timer.post_execute)
    events.append(timer.pre_execute)
    events.append(timer.pre_run_cell)
    events.append(timer.post_execute)

# This doesn't unregister events correctly?
def unload_ipython_extension(ip):
    # print("UNLOADING")
    ip.events.unregister('pre_execute',  events[0])
    ip.events.unregister('pre_run_cell', events[1])
    ip.events.unregister('post_execute', events[2])
```

unregistering the events doesn't seem to work as intended, but it's not too important in this case.

Extensions can be auto-loaded using `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions` in [the config file.](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#python-configuration-files)